# XText and ProposalProvider for language element with multiple references

Tags: xtext

I have little bit of a problem with ScopeProvider.

I have a language definition like the following.

```
Element:
 LanguageElement1 | LanguageElement2 | LanguageElement3 | LanguageElement4 | LanguageElement5 | CompositeElement;

CompositeElement:
 'compositeElement' name=ID
 'languageElements1' languageElements1+=[LanguageElement1]
 'languageElements2' languageElements2+=[LanguageElement2]
 'languageElements3' languageElements3+=[LanguageElement3]
 'languageElements4' languageElements4+=[LanguageElement4]
 'languageElements5' languageElements5+=[LanguageElement5];
```

I had a fitting ScopingProvider geschrieben, which works also.

My problem, in Eclipse IDE when I try to place under CompositeElement under 'languageElements1' I want that only the Elements with type 'LanguageElement1' are displayed in Eclipse IDE proposal pop-up but unfortunately while under CompositeElement other references to LanguageElement2, LanguageElement3, LanguageElement4, LanguageElement5, all possibles references are displayed.

I debugged the Eclipse IDE and landed responsible code part.

In XText 2.27, org.eclipse.xtext.linking.lazy.LazyLinkingResource code line 149,

```
final CancelIndicator monitor = mon == null ? CancelIndicator.NullImpl : mon;
    TreeIterator<Object> iterator = EcoreUtil.getAllContents(this, true);
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        operationCanceledManager.checkCanceled(monitor);
        InternalEObject source = (InternalEObject) iterator.next();
        EStructuralFeature[] eStructuralFeatures = ((EClassImpl.FeatureSubsetSupplier) source.eClass()
                .getEAllStructuralFeatures()).crossReferences();
        if (eStructuralFeatures != null) {
            for (EStructuralFeature crossRef : eStructuralFeatures) {
                operationCanceledManager.checkCanceled(monitor);
                resolveLazyCrossReference(source, crossRef);
            }
        }
    }
```

This code Snippet goes over all Structural Features and try to display all cross references but what I want

```
compositeElement blabla
   languageElements1
```

when I am under 'languageElements1' only LanguageElement1's are displayed in proposal pop-up.

Now I find some post how this can be done pre Eclipse XText 2.9 API but I can't find a way to convert to current API.

So any ideas?

Comment: the problem is the metamodel has only one cross reference of type Element and not 5 different ones (`languageElements1+=` used for all 5). you may look into the node model in the content assist context and try to find out if you can find the keyword there.

Comment: Sry, that was a typo from my copy/paste, naturally it is 'languageElements1+=', 'languageElements2+=', 'languageElements3+=', 'languageElements4+=', 'languageElements5+='

Comment: but with that i cannot reproduce. after languageElements1 i see only elements of type LanguageElement1 displayed. 
I propose you debug scoping to find out why you get more (e.g. org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.contentassist.AbstractJavaBasedContentProposalProvider.ReferenceProposalCreator.lookupCrossReference(EObject, EReference, ICompletionProposalAcceptor, Predicate<IEObjectDescription>, Function<IEObjectDescription, ICompletionProposal>))